# On textbox change change label value to HTML (array)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a array of textbox and labels which are toggled in a html table, say the label vl be visible on first and then on the row click the text box are visible , but the problem is on that row if i change the text box value the label value should also change but hear in my case am not able to do it.

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vmj5h2a8/10/)

HTML:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" width="100%" id="table1">
    <tr>
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
        <th>Column3</th>
        <th>Column4</th>
        <th>Column5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>data1</label>
            <input type="text" value="data1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data2</label>
            <input type="text" value="data2" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data3</label>
            <input type="text"  value="data3"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data4</label>
            <input type="text" value="data4"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data5</label>
            <input type="text" value="data5"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>data6</label>
            <input type="text" value="data6" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data7</label>
            <input type="text"  value="data7"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data8</label>
            <input type="text" value="data8" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data9</label>
            <input type="text" value="data9" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data10</label>
            <input type="text" value="data10" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input id="printdata" type="button" value="printdata" />
<div class="showresult">1: <span></span></div>
<div class="showresult">2: <span></span></div>
<div class="showresult">3: <span></span></div>
<div class="showresult">4: <span></span></div>
<div class="showresult">5: <span></span></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#table1 input').hide();
$('#printdata').fadeTo(0, 0);

// This shows or hides the button deppending on the inputs
$('#table1 tr').on('change keyup click', function() {
    var text = '';
    $('input', this).each(function(){
        text += $(this).val();
    });

    if (text !='')
    {
        $('#printdata').fadeTo(0, 100);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#printdata').fadeTo(0, 0);
    }
});

$('#table1 tr').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($( e.target ).is("input") || $( e.target ).is("th") ) {
        return;
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        $('input', this).toggle();
        $('label', this).toggle();
    } else { 
        $('tr.selected input').hide();
        $('tr.selected label').toggle();
        $('tr.selected').toggleClass('selected');
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        $('label', this).toggle();
        $('input', this).toggle();
    }
});



$('#printdata').click(function () {
    $('.showresult').each(function (index) {
        $('span', this).html('');
        $('span', this).html($('#table1 .selected input').eq(index).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add this code:-

```
$('#table1 tr').on('change','[type="text"]', function(e) {
  $(this).prev('label').text($(this).val());
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vmj5h2a8/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's what you need to add to make your code working:

```
$('#table1 input').each(function(idx, input) {
    var jqInput = $(input);
    var label = jqInput.parent().find("label")
    jqInput.change(function() {
        label.text(jqInput.val())
    })
})
```

However, this is a slippery road.
You're trying to maintain some state, display it in different views...
You will always have some sort of data synchronization bug with this approach.
You need to use some sort of MVC to make your life easier and code more stable.